# How to install gensim for IronPython?

Tags: c#, python, pip, ironpython, gensim

I am trying to use gensim through IronPython, but installing this package seems to be impossible. I tried it with IronPython 2.7.7. with the following commands:

```
ipy -X:Frames -m install ensurepip
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install setuptools
ipy -X:Frames -m pip install gensim
```

Does anyone know if it is possible to use the gensim-package in IronPython? Otherwise, I have to switch a part of my .NET application over to CPython, where I have gensim working.

Thanks in advance!